# Continuously running windows service

Tags: c#, windows, service

I'm new to writing WindowsServices. I used to make web-applications.

I need to make this service that checks directories for files. If a certain trigger-file is present, the files in the directory get copied, and other stuff gets done.

My service is ready, almost.
It works fine, but I have an issue.
If the trigger-file is present, the copying and processing starts.
But at the same time, the service keeps checking my directories.
So at a given point, it comes back to the directory that is being copied.

How can I prevent it from recopying the directory?
(I hope I am clear in my explanation)

Comment: Explanation is mostly clear, but I suggest you post some code so we can see what it really happening and offer informed assistance.

Comment: add a flag on the directory, and when it goes to copy one, it verifies that a flag (name of directory) isn't turned on already

Comment: Like, push the directory path into a List, then remove it from the List when it's finished

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution, just when I was reading my question again and looking at your comments.
I can simply delete my trigger-file and then the service should skip the folder.

Sorry for your trouble.